# display: grid with dynamically number of rows and columns, and also dynamic height / rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm struggling achieving the layout that you can see in [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GHaG.png).

Long story short, I'm trying to create a dynamic layout where I will have elements with different heights and dynamic number of columns / rows based on number of elements.

Rules:

- If I have 6 elements -> 3 columns 2 rows.
- If I have 2 elements -> 2 columns 1 row
- If I have 1 element -> 1 column 1 row

I was thinking that I might use display: grid, but then I realized that they won't keep their margins equals if the elements have different heights.

Anybody had same problem?

More examples [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyf2r.png).

Comment: Please provide a [repro] for debugging details. Why work with margins at all? CSS-Grid uses the `gap` property to space elements apart equally.

Comment: hey @tacoshy I have edited the description and added more examples. The margin part is not so important, I just wanted to let you know that the elements needs to have the same distance between each other.